# Random number will not show up in text box

Tags: c#, dice

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RollTheDice
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnDice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int Roll; 

            Random rand = new Random();

            Roll = rand.Next(0,10);

            diceDisplay.Text = btnDice.ToString();

        }
    }
}
```

Not able to output number to the text field, there is no error it just will not work.

When the button is clicked system. error does show on it but does not show on the build

Comment: Well, you're not setting the text to the number. You're setting it to btnDice.ToString(). Set diceDisplay.Text = roll.ToString().

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning `random number` to the TextBox but assigning the Button.ToString:

```
int Roll; 

Random rand = new Random();

Roll = rand.Next(0,10);

diceDisplay.Text = Roll.ToString();  //modified
```

Also precise your code and replace with just one line:

```
diceDisplay.Text = new Random().Next(0,10).ToString();
```

Comment: Be careful with this, you generally don't use `Random` as a function scope variable. I would one-line it, but with a pre-existing `Random` object. You aren't in a loop, so its *technically* ok, but good practice and all :)

Comment: I find no difference in this scenario. He is already saving it in a textbox.

Comment: Repeated calls (if you could click fast enough) would result in the same value being displayed. Storing it off fixes this problem (same reason you don't use `Random` in a loop). You *cant* click fast enough, so its ok (hence the qualification for my comment).

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I think you meant: *(same reason you don't use `new Random();` in a loop).*  Minor detail.

Comment: @LarsTech Yes, that is what I meant. Everywhere I said `Random` `new Random()` should be substituted.

Answer (score 0):

You should use roll.ToString() instead of btnDice.ToString();